# Linq to SQL Extended Data Classes - Share a DataContext

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm using the partial classes feature of Linq2SQL to add some helper methods to my objects.

The problem is that I need to perform some additional database queries in these helper methods, so I have to create a new DataContext every time.

I want to reuse a DataContext for all database operations within a single web service query.

If I keep the helper methods in a separate class, I simply initialize the context just once in the class constructor and reuse it for all methods.

With extended Linq2SQL classes I can't figure out how to get a reference to the same DataContext that was used for retrieving the current object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't really, as such. Not least, because LINQ-to-SQL can work with POCOs. You must handle your data-context manually, and keep hold of them if you want to use them at various points. One approach here could be to make the method available from the data-context rather than the leaf object - then you are *forced* to know the data-context.

In some cases, keeping a data-context available against a "request" or "context" object may be a good way to get around this, since that is usually trivially available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to get the creating data context. You have to pass it in to your custom methods. Inside my entity partial classes, I do a lot of operations like this:

```
public void Query()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
         Query(db);
    }
}

public void Query(DataContext db)
{
    /* do something with the db */
}
```

This gives you the flexibility to pass in the DataContext that created the object or just use a new one in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I need to perform some additional database queries
>   in these helper methods, so I have to create a new DataContext every
>   time.

No you don't. Prevent adding business logic to your L2S entities. It will become an unmanagable tangled ball of mud in no time. Place those operations in service classes that use those entities. For instance, use the [command/handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [query/handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) patterns.

> I want to reuse a DataContext for all database operations within a
>   single web service query.

What ever you do, prevent an `DataContext` instance from being used by multiple threads. What you can do is have one `DataContext` per web request.